# add docvars to dfm from separate data.frame r

Tags: r, topic-modeling, quanteda, dfm

After spending much time developing the proper corpus (e.g. stopwords, tf-idf) I created a `dtm` in the `tm`package and ran my topic model.

I then proceeded to compare the topics to some document level covariates of interest, only to learn that `stm` allows you to estimate models using document-level covariates of interest.

I have successfully converted my `dtm` to a `dfm` in `quanteda` and would like to add my covariates to the `dfm` before converting to a `stm`.

I have a `data.frame` with my covariates of interest which share the same `row.id` as the `dfm`.

I am looking for a solution to merge the covariates from the `data.frame` with the `dfm`.

I have tried:

`docvars` and `metadoc` in `quanteda` to no avail.

For example,

`docvars(dfm, docnames(dfm)) <- df$covariate`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need `cbind.dfm`: Combine a dfm with another dfm, or numeric, or matrix object, returning a dfm with the combined documents or features, respectively.

Comment: @phiver, thanks for the response. It looks like that function is specific to merging two `dfm` rather than a `dfm` and a `data.frame` by their respective `id`. When I run

Comment: When I run `cbind(dfm, df)` I get back `Error: not-yet-implemented method for cbind2(<dfm>, <data.frame>).
 ->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.`

Comment: try turning your df, or relevant columns of your df into a matrix. cbind(dfm, matrix) works fine.

Comment: I am getting the following error, I think it is due to the fact that my covariates are characters: `Error in asMethod(object) : invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_geMatrix`. When I convert it to as.factor I get `Error in cbind(deparse.level, ...) : all arguments must be dfm objects`. I have had success converting the `dfm` to a `data.frame` and merging the two that way: `dfm.data.frame <- convert(dfmm, to = "data.frame")
with.meta <- merge(dfm.data.frame, df, by="document.id")` but now I need to convert the data.frame back to a `dfm`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to figure it out. In the end it was very simple. I just needed to specify the `data.frame` as a whole, not just my columns of interest. Here is the code:

`dfm.w.metadata <- convert(dfm, to = "stm", docvars = df)`